# Angular 5 upload and show picture

Tags: angular5

I'm trying to upload a picture and show it in the same interface, 
but after uploading it doesn't work well.

When I run ng serve, then the picture shows correctly! 
Any help ?

Comment: How are you doing it? Can you please post the related code and be little more clear?

Comment: <input id="single" name="single"  type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" hidden>    
  <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" [src]="pub.id"  alt="Card image cap">